# Ordering the days of the week

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a column of dates in my data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':t})
```

I want to know which row is the first Friday, the second Friday, the nth Friday of each month.  I'd like to do this for every day of the week, Monday through Friday, Saturday, and Sunday.

Right now, I can do it like this:

```
df['dow'] = df.dates.dt.day_name()
df['month'] = df.dates.dt.month_name()

frames = []

for name, frame in df.groupby(['dow','month']):

    frame.loc[:,'dow_order'] = np.arange(frame.shape[0])

    frames.append(frame)


pd.concat(frames)
```

This returns

```
    dates        dow    month   dow_order
94  2019-04-05  Friday  April   0
101 2019-04-12  Friday  April   1
108 2019-04-19  Friday  April   2
115 2019-04-26  Friday  April   3
213 2019-08-02  Friday  August  0
```

So know I know that '2019-04-05' is the first friday of April.

This loop is a little slow for just 1 year, and I am working with many years.  Is there a more efficient, or simpler, way of performing this computation?

Comment: So you what is the expected output, in the beginning of your question you talk about mondays, then the output is Fridays, could you be more clear about your problem?

Comment: Be more clear about the question

Comment: @DanielMesejo I've edited my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':t})

df['dow'] = df.dates.dt.day_name()
df['month'] = df.dates.dt.month_name()

df['dow_order'] = df.groupby(['dow', 'month']).cumcount()
df = df.sort_values(['dow', 'month'])

print(df.head(10))
```

**Output**

```
         dates     dow     month  dow_order
94  2019-04-05  Friday     April          0
101 2019-04-12  Friday     April          1
108 2019-04-19  Friday     April          2
115 2019-04-26  Friday     April          3
213 2019-08-02  Friday    August          0
220 2019-08-09  Friday    August          1
227 2019-08-16  Friday    August          2
234 2019-08-23  Friday    August          3
241 2019-08-30  Friday    August          4
339 2019-12-06  Friday  December          0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `dow_order` , you do not need create `month` and *`day of week`* in two column

```
df['dow_order']=df.groupby(df.dates.dt.strftime('%m-%w')).cumcount()
```